# phpmailer taking email sending time more than 20 seconds

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am facing issue phpmailer sending email very slow.... **taking about 25-30 seconds** to send. **Email getting delivered** but script execution time is more...

I have create a simple test.php for testing. It also took about 24-25 seconds to send email...

code of `**test.php**` is as follows

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer691/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer691/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer691/src/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'mail.mysite.co.in';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'support@mysite.co.in';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxxxx';                               //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('support@mysite.co.in', 'My Site Name Test Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('mypersonalemail@gmail.com', 'Dzine');     //Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('support@mysite.co.in', 'My Site Name Test Mailer Reply To');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//Attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

**Debug showing following information**

```
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-sun.ownmyserver.com ESMTP Exim 4.96 #2 Tue, 05 Dec 2023 13:30:13 +0530 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mysite.co.in
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-sun.ownmyserver.com Hello www.mysite.co.in [103.117.212.238]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPECONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
            2023-12-05 08:00:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<support@mysite.co.in>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<mypersonalemail@gmail.com>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 5 Dec 2023 08:00:13 +0000
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Dzine <mypersonalemail@gmail.com>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: My Website Name Test Mailer <support@mysite.co.in>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: My Website Name Test Mailer Reply To <support@mysite.co.in>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <4uWHKnxynr6wFM9UQOi5TNmqhL8RM5ET2EHchInGWJg@www.mysite.co.in>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.9.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1=_4uWHKnxynr6wFM9UQOi5TNmqhL8RM5ET2EHchInGWJg"
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_4uWHKnxynr6wFM9UQOi5TNmqhL8RM5ET2EHchInGWJg
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_4uWHKnxynr6wFM9UQOi5TNmqhL8RM5ET2EHchInGWJg
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_4uWHKnxynr6wFM9UQOi5TNmqhL8RM5ET2EHchInGWJg--
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
            2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
            2023-12-05 08:00:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1rAQLe-0000rM-1r
            2023-12-05 08:00:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
            2023-12-05 08:00:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 sun.ownmyserver.com closing connection
            Message has been sent
```

Tried mail, Sendmail option. Asked hosting provider. They said at server everything is ok

Comment: No... I am trying solutions since last 3-4 days without luck

Answer (score 2):

Your provider is correct - everything *is* OK. This is the critical part of the log:

```
2023-12-05 08:00:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2023-12-05 08:00:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1rAQLe-0000rM-1r
```

note the difference in timestamps. This time is being taken by the mail server after you've completed submitting your message, not your script, so there is nothing that you can do about it *within* your script.

What you *can* do is to rearrange how you go about sending. Instead of sending interactively, during page processing, hand off the email send to a queue process that can do the waiting instead of your user. You can do this at two different levels - either in your app's stack (e.g. using Laravel's queues), or by running a local mail server and submitting to that (which will be *much* faster).

SMTP is fundamentally unsuited to interactive use during page processing, but that doesn't prevent many people trying and failing. Each command in SMTP has a 10-*minute* timeout, so it can quite legitimately take a very long time to send, and in fact many mail servers deliberately slow you down for traffic control or grey listing purposes.

Comment: ReactPHP might be interesting for this as well. It allows async processing in PHP (well, technically it simulates async I think, but it works)

Comment: Isn't this just rehashing the same answer from the indicated duplicate from the comments.  Especially as it's your answer.

Comment: ok... thanx for clear suggestion... I will work  it.... thnx

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same problem, though this issue is somewhat further along, that duplicate wasn't flagged at the time, and I did write it over 9 years ago (nothing changes, huh!).